# How to filter/facet for records that lead with a hyphen

Tags: algolia

I've tried to filter by a certain facet, but some of the keys that have leading hyphens, **`-`**, do not seem to filter the result set.

i.e. given the following JSON

```
{
    key: ["-does", "-not", "-work", "but,thisworks"]
}
```

Trying to add a facet such as key:-does, will never filter the result set.

Has anyone else ran into this situation and/or know a solution?

Comment: I know nothing about Algolia, but the FAQ says that [punctuation characters aren't indexed by default](https://www.algolia.com/doc/faq/searching/how-can-i-search-for-punctuation-special-characters). Could this be the problem?

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie: This was a good idea, but facets in Algolia are actually doing full string comparisons. The punctuation not indexed is for the textual search of the query.

Answer (score 0):

Facet filters in Algolia support a specific type called *excludes*. When leading with a dash, the engine will actually exclude the items containing this value from the results list when used with [`facetFilters`](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/ruby/parameters#facetfilters-deprecated) which is now deprecated.

However, the engine has a new parameter, with a clearer syntax, which the algolia.com dashboard isn't yet using if it's where you're trying it, called [`filters`](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/ruby/parameters#filters).

This parameter will accept this query and look for records having "-does" as a facet value:

```
index.search('', { filters: "key:-does" })
```

If you want to use the exclusion syntax, this parameter accepts a `NOT` operator, that you could use like this:

```
index.search('', { filters: "NOT key:does" })
```